# Separate a column of variating length into rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a variable that has multiple entries, and the number of entries changes:

```
name    tags
john    "a, b, c"
tyler   "b"
ron     "c, b"
 :        :
```

etc.

I'd like to separate the tags into multiple entries, like:

```
name    tags
john    "a"
john    "b"
john    "c"
tyler   "b"
ron     "c"
ron     "b"
 :       :
```

My idea is to split the tags column into `tags1 tags2 ... tags(max number)` and then joining them back with `separate %>% pivot_longer %>% drop_na` but i feel like there's definitively an easier way to do this. What can I do?

Quick code to reproduce the example dataframe:
`example = data.frame(name = c('john', 'tyler', 'ron'), tags = c('a, b, c', 'b', 'c, b'))`

Comment: this is what `tidyr::separate_rows()` is for.

Comment: Or `tidyr::separate_longer_delim`.